# Fatal error during compilation org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have a grails 2.2.4 app that works perfectly fine. However, it does not start when I try to integrate the `spring-security-ui` plugin into the app. I added the following to my `BuilConfig.groovy`

```
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
```

After this, when I try to run the app I get the following:

```
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [spring-security-core-1.2.7.3]. Do you want to update to [spring-security-core-2.0-RC3]? [y,n] n
n
| Plugin spring-security-core-2.0-RC3 install aborted
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.7.2]. Do you want to update to [jquery-1.11.1]? [y,n] n
n
| Plugin jquery-1.11.1 install aborted
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-ui-1.8.24]. Do you want to update to [jquery-ui-1.10.3]? [y,n] n
n
| Plugin jquery-ui-1.10.3 install aborted
| Plugin jquery-ui-1.10.3 install aborted.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL 
[jar:file:/Users/birdy/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails/grails-core/jars/grails-core-2.2.4.jar!/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/DirectoryWatcher$FileChangeListener.class]; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

When I use the --stacktrace option I get the following stacktrace:

```
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:220)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:62)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:61)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:45)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor
    ... 45 more
```

**What I've tried**

- I've tried to `grails compile --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace` but that results in same error.
- I also upgraded Spring security plugin to `spring-security-core-2.0-RC3` but got the same error

Comment: Without looking at your full BuildConfig, my educated guess is  ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2" has a conflicting transient dependency that ivy isn't figuring out so you'll need to add a proper 'exclusion' to allow a consistent dependency graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"` in my **BuildConfig.groovy**. Documentation for the security plugin is not the best.

Hope that helps.